# Show $\vec R \cdot ( \nabla \times \vec R) = 0$

Tags: calculus

The vector field $\vec R(\vec x)$ is everywhere parallel to the normals to a family of surfaces $f(\vec x)=$ constant. Show that $\vec R \cdot ( \nabla \times \vec R) = 0$. I'm not sure where to even start with this. Can someone give me a hint as to how to start this?

Answer (score 0):

Since $\vec{R}$ is parallel to the normal of a family of surfaces $f(\vec{x}) = \operatorname{const}$, then $\vec{R} \parallel \nabla f$. Observe
\begin{align}
\nabla f \cdot (\nabla \times \nabla f) = \nabla \cdot \vec{0}.
\end{align}

Comment: And just how does that help here?  All that shows is that $\vec R\cdot \nabla \times \vec R=\vec R\cdot \nabla \times \vec R$.

Comment: @Dr.MV You are right. I have made the correction.